# Which camera did it come from?

Tags: image, image-comparison

So, here's the situation. I have direct access to two devices, and can take as many pictures as I want with each. Both devices are the same make and model, and do not save any metadata that would distinguish one from the other. This means that they do not leave any specific identifiers in the metadata. I also have a picture that I know came from one of them, but I don't know which. Let's call this photo "photoX". Both devices are the iPhone SE.

So here is the question: is there anything I can do with the two cameras and the pictures I can take with them to figure out which one photoX was taken from?

(Apparently I have to stress this, but metadata searching will not be able to work. I am aware of this.)

Comment: Phil Harvey (the creator of `exiftool`) says not... http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=7609.0

Comment: @MarkSetchell I was specifically saying that the metadata did not have any identifiers to eliminate that as a possible way of doing it. I am very aware (after finding out from a different question that I asked) that you cannot use the metadata to identify the device.

Comment: You could set the time incorrectly on one of the phones by, say 1 year, and then you would know.

Comment: @MarkSetchell except that couldn't possibly tell me which device the picture came from given that it is a picture that was taken in the past. Unless you know a way for me to time travel, this can't work.

Comment: No need to be snarky - I am trying to help you. You said *"the pictures I can take"* not *"the pictures I have taken"*.

Comment: @MarkSetchell actually, it was serious. If you know a way to time travel, it would actually be more helpful than whatever the answer is to this question. But anyways, it says "the pictures I can take" but it then says "figure out which one the photo..." I would like to point out the words "the photo" which refer back to the one of unknown origin. I will clarify that as it seems to be unclear.

Comment: Maybe take a trial of this software http://www.forensic-pathways.com/forensic-image-analyser/

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'll try it and see if it works. Thanks for your suggestions. Even if I do seen a bit snarky, I do appreciate every response.